# How to populate all members in an ownership chain using VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm hoping someone can help with the VBA code.
I'm trying to populate all members in an ownership chain. The relationships are like below:

[image]

So basically, B owns A and C. A owns D. C owns E and F.
The outcome I'm expecting is B: A, C, D, E, F

Thank you so much!

I am not sure how to write the VBA code.

Comment: Similar but for managers/reports - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437704/excel-macro-to-filter-direct-indirect-reports/74449753#74449753

Comment: Hi Tim - Thank you! How to add one condition to the loop? Say when career level is S1 and S2, stop searching for employees under his/her supervision.

Comment: I don't see any data for career level in your post, or any code, so it's difficult to make a concrete suggestion, but in the linked question you'd check the career level of the report isn't S1 or S2 before running the line `mgrs.Add arrEmpId(r, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library to be able to use the `Dictionary` structure.

Here is the vba code I would use then:

```vb
Sub ownership_chain()
    Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim entity As String
    Dim owner As String
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim key2 As Variant
    Dim res As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim count As Integer
    
    For iRow = 2 To 6 ' to adapt to your file
        entity = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
        owner = Cells(iRow, 2).Value
        If Not dic.Exists(owner) Then
            dic.Add owner, New Collection
        End If
        dic(owner).Add entity
    Next iRow
    
    For Each key In dic
        res(key) = 0
    Next key
    
    For Each key In dic
        For Each key2 In dic(key)
            res(key2) = 0
        Next key2
    Next key
    
    count = 0
    For Each key In res
        If count = 0 Then
            display = display & key & ": "
        Else:
            display = display & key & ", "
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next key
    
    Debug.Print Left$(display, Len(display) - 2)

End Sub
```

Hope this helps